# Coinbase Wallet API python Authentication Error, Invalid Signature

Tags: python, authentication, coinbase-api

Python 3.4 Coinbase Wallet API V2

---

I have been stuck for some time trying to figure out while this buy call 
(and other api calls like get_payment_methods() and get_accounts() ) run into authentication errors. I have successfully been able to run some of these api calls alone in a separate file.

---

**What Does Not Work**:

```
class api_call(object):                                                                                                           

      def __init__(self):                                                                                                           
          self.CB_key = xxxxxxxx                                                                                                        
          self.CB_secret = yyyyyyyy                                                                                                    
          self.CB_account = zzzzzzzzz                                                                                                    
          self.CB_payment_method = aaaaaaaaaa

      def buy_c(self, exchange, b_amount):                                                                                
          client = Client(self.CB_key, self.CB_secret)                                                                          
          buy = client.buy(self.CB_account, amount=str(b_amount), currency="USD", payment_method=self.CB_payment_method)

api = api_call()
buy = api.buy('COIN-BS', 1)
```

I have triple checked my accounts, keys and secrets and have also tried hard coding them inside the class definition instead of using **init** members.

---

**What Works:**

```
 from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
 client = Client(<api_key>, <api_secret>)

 buy = client.buy('zzzzzzzz', amount='1', currency="USD", payment_method='aaaaaaaaaa')
```

---

The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "api_call.py", line 126, in <module>
   buy = api.buy('COIN-BS', 1)
File "api_call.py", line 110, in buy
   buy = client.buy_c( self.CB_account, amount=str(amount), currency="USD", payment_method="XXXXXXXXXXXX")
File "/home/LA/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/coinbase/wallet/client.py", line 381, in buy
   response = self._post('v2', 'accounts', account_id, 'buys', data=params)
File "/home/LA/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/coinbase/wallet/client.py", line 132, in _post
   return self._request('post', *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/LA/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/coinbase/wallet/client.py", line 116, in _request
   return self._handle_response(response)
File "/home/LA/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/coinbase/wallet/client.py", line 125, in _handle_response
   raise build_api_error(response)

coinbase.wallet.error.AuthenticationError: APIError(id=authentication_error): invalid signature
```

Im thinking that the problem may be due to the use of the API buy method inside of a definition of a class file, that is my api_call.py class.I think this because I can call the buy method ( and others ) just fine from separate files and even outside of the class indentations inside of api_call.py.

---

Does anyone have any idea why this would raise an Authentication Error? I have looked around in [error.py](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-python/blob/master/coinbase/wallet/error.py), but haven't yet found a clue on why this might be happening.

As always, any help or thoughts regarding the matter is much appreciated!

---

**EDIT**

After running the working and non working code on the same file, I was successfully able to make both buys. After trying a few other things, I found that apparently any POSTs to the API using those globally modified variables, command line arguments, and updated object member variables will produce this authentication error. Is this supposed to happen?

```
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client

#Globals
key = 'xxxxxx'
secret = 'yyyyyy'
account = 'zzzzzzz'
payment = 'aaaaaaa'

class api_call(object):                                                                                                           

  def __init__(self):                                                                                                           
      self.CB_key = None                                                                                                        
      self.CB_secret = None                                                                                                    
      self.CB_account = None                                                                                                    
      self.CB_payment_method = None

  def buy_c(self, exchange, b_amount):                                                                                
      client = Client(key, secret)                                                                          
      buy = client.buy(account, amount=str(b_amount), currency="USD", payment_method=payment)

client = Client(key, secret)
buy = client.buy(account, amount='1', currency="USD", payment_method=payment)

api = api_call()
buy = api.buy_c('COIN-BS', 1)
```

Comment: can you post the working version?

Comment: @James For sure. It works just fine as a small script as I have edited in.

Comment: To reduce the chance of a scoping issue you caused, can we put the non working and working samples into the same file, pull all your variables into global constants, and use the same constants for both versions? See if you still get the same issues. If you do, update the code here cause that would definitively prove you are using the same authentication values.

Comment: It worked when using the global variables for both. However, wont work when I access the values with of the object itself. ( i.e. self.CB_key ) Any suggestions?

Comment: lets see the new code.

Comment: @James New code Posted

Answer (score 0):

after extensive static analysis, I have concluded this is probably your issue.

```
buy = api.buy('COIN-BS', 1) -> buy = api.buy_c('COIN-BS', 1)
```

also figure out why your stack trace has `client.buy_c` instead of `client.buy`

Comment: This was an accident when writing up my code on the page. It actually is not the issue. Thanks for noticing though!